# Is there any functionality in puppeteer with mocha similar to dataProvider in TestNG?

Tags: javascript, node.js, automation, puppeteer, browser-automation

I was looking for similar functionality in puppeteer with mocha as dataProvider in TestNG testing framework . Can anyone suggest how to achieve it in puppeteer.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built on methods for that in Mocha. But you can easily achieve it with the simple `forEach` method.

```
 const SITES = ['https://github.com', 'https://google.com'];

 SUITES.forEach(expected => {
   describe('Suites:', () => {
     it(`go to the ${expected} url`, => async () {
       await page.goto(expected);
     });
   });
 });
```

Or use the [mocha-testdata](https://github.com/pandell/mocha-testdata) library.

By the way, in [jest](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/api#describeeachtable-name-fn-timeout) you can easily do it.